# jquery: howto return caller-id when using wildcard selectors

Tags: json, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-callback

i'm using jquery to invoke JSON-requests and they're triggered form a bunch of autocomplete-fields. I use wildcard-selector and now need to find out which ac-field that fired the event.

```
...
$( "[id*='_lookupCmb']" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      ...
      ...
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        //here I want to get the name of the id calling the request...
```

Thankful for any quickfix or guidance in wiser solution.

ATB

//tom joad

Comment: also, if you want access to jquery functions: $(this). For instance $(this).val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe under the ui argument object is an `elem`, and `origElem`, or something of a similar name (might be `target`, break inside using firebug and drill into it to find out for sure); then you can simply say `$(ui.elem).attr('id')`.